# Django Google App Engine: 502 Bad Gateway, already installed package not recognized

Tags: django, google-app-engine, deployment

I'm deploying Django in Google App Engine.

I get 502 Bad Gateway and in the log I get the following error:

> 2021-03-08 12:08:18 default[20210308t130512]  Traceback (most recent call last):    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker      worker.init_process()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 92, in init_process      super().init_process()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process      self.load_wsgi()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi      self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi      self.callable = self.load()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load      return self.load_wsgiapp()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp      return util.import_app(self.app_uri)    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app      mod = importlib.import_module(module)    File "/opt/python3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)    File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import    File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load    File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked    File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked    File "", line 790, in exec_module    File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed    File "/srv/main.py", line 1, in       from django_project.wsgi import application    File "/srv/django_project/wsgi.py", line 16, in       application = get_wsgi_application()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application      django.setup(set_prefix=False)    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 19, in setup      configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 82, in **getattr**      self._setup(name)    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 69, in _setup      self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 170, in **init**      mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)    File "/opt/python3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)    File "/srv/django_project/settings.py", line 84, in       import pymysql  # noqa: 402  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'

The problem is that I already installed `pymysql`, in fact if I run `pip3 install pymysql`, I get `Requirement already satisfied: ...`

Why is that?
Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Here's `requirements.txt`:

```
asgiref==3.3.1
attrs==20.3.0
Automat==20.2.0
certifi==2020.12.5
cffi==1.14.4
chardet==4.0.0
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==3.4.1
cssselect==1.1.0
Django==3.1.6
django-phonenumber-field==5.0.0
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.8
hyperlink==21.0.0
idna==2.10
incremental==17.5.0
instaloader==4.6.1
itemadapter==0.2.0
itemloaders==1.0.4
jmespath==0.10.0
jsonfield==3.1.0
lxml==4.6.2
parsel==1.6.0
phonenumberslite==8.12.18
progress==1.5
Protego==0.1.16
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.20
PyDispatcher==2.0.5
PyHamcrest==2.0.2
pyOpenSSL==20.0.1
pytz==2021.1
queuelib==1.5.0
requests==2.25.1
schedule==0.6.0
Scrapy==2.4.1
semantic-version==2.8.5
service-identity==18.1.0
setuptools-rust==0.11.6
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
toml==0.10.2
urllib3==1.26.3
w3lib==1.22.0
zope.interface==5.2.0
```

Comment: What is in your requriements.txt?

Comment: @gaefan Done, have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `pip3 install pymysql` in your local computer, this does not mean that when you deploy the app this module is packaged. In fact GAE attempts to install everything at build time using your `requirements.txt` file so it doesn't matter if you installed everything in your PC since GAE will not use what you have in local (talking about packages installed with `pip`).

Checking your `requirements.txt` file I do not see that the package `PyMySQL` is added. You should add it to that file and attempt to deploy again.

Comment: Thanks! But how is that? I mean, isn't the important thing that I have the packages installed in the virtual env so that when I deploy it deploys all the packages with it?

Comment: App Engine will [use the packages in the requirements.txt](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/specifying-dependencies#:~:text=The%20dependencies%20installed%20by%20App%20Engine%20during%20deployment%20are%20based%20on%20the%20contents%20of%20the%20requirements.txt%20file%2C%20not%20the%20contents%20of%20the%20env%2F%20directory.). Using a venv is recommended so you can isolate the system packages from the "requirements.txt" packages when running the app locally.

Answer (score 0):

**"pymysql" package** is missing (not installed) according to the message below from your error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'

So, you need to run this command below to install **"pymysql"**:

```
pip install pymysql
```